# Auth0 with .Net Core ASP MVC to WebAPI Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, auth0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core ASP MVC app that authenticates with Auth0 and properly returns an access token and id token.  I would like to use the access token for authentication as described in the docs [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi).  However, passing in an access token results in a 401 with "invalid audience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky as the docs are woefully inadequate.  In order to get the correct token for the API, you must get a token with the same audience at login (or otherwise).  The end part of [this example](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-sample/tree/ebd528d6ac46f3b8c5b26e0a5872f9a97e8fd433/01-Login#passing-additional-parameters-to-the-authorize-endpoint) on github was key.

```
Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            // add any custom parameters here
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", "myapiaudience");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```